# Ignore A Row When Reading CSV In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Having problems when performing calculations in a Pandas dataframe... Here's a sample CSV (see picture): [image: sample CSV]

My problem is that since it reads the row in italics e.g. Data Type (row 2), it treats all values as strings instead of their correct data type i.e. float, degrees, etc. Is there a way I can get it to ignore this row when reading the CSV e.g.

df = pd.read_CSV('sample CSV', ignore row 2)

That way it will read in like this (see other picture) and assume correct data types:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list to `skiprows` to skip only that row. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> skiprows : list-like or integer or callable, default None
>
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.

Try:

```
pd.read_csv('my.csv', skiprows=[1])
```

Beware that python starts counting from 0. So that column (in python) in 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skiprows=[0]`, for more details you can refer to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('Your Filename', skiprows=[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `header` argument in `read_CSV`. For example:

```
df = pd.read_CSV('sample CSV', header=2)
```

This won't assign the names in the first row. You could probably achieved this by passing the column names manually:

```
df = pd.read_CSV('sample CSV', header=2, names=['UTC Time', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'])
```

You could even get the names programmatically:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as fh:
    names = fr.readline().split(',')
df = pd.read_CSV('sample CSV', header=2, names=names)
```

(all the code is untested)